# How to get my Django app in a real server?

Tags: django

I'm starting with web development, the last week I just write an HMTL, JavaScript and PHP scripts and get some very basic working properly in my web page, I used Cyberduck to get my files working in my web page. This week I want to use Django to develop faster, I have got my web page working locally but I have not been able to find a tutorial to get my Django app working in my server, I have a hosting service.

Comment: Refer this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 3):

1. Develop a simple django app following django docs:
   For Python 2.7.X and Django 1.11:        https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/
   For Python 3.7.X and Django 2.1:
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/
2. Then try hosting the same in pythonanywhere site: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject